# What is the best way to handle data from a .then outside of the .then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am using google's geocoding api to convert an address into a coordinate.

I have the following fetch to accomplish that.

```js
    fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${prop.address}&key=${
      getEnv().APP_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY
    }`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location));
```

This successfully console logs the objects that I want to extract from this json.

What I want to know is: How do I use this object within the rest of my code?

For context this code is within a react component

[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEqJH.png)

And I want to use the coordinate object I get back inside of the `<GoogleMap/>` component's center prop and the `<Marker/>` component's position prop.

Comment: A better way is certainly `async` and `await`.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding async React rendering](/q/55142538/90527)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the hooks `useState` to store the data and `useEffect` to operate on it. You'll probably want something along the lines of:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  [ data, setData ] = useState(null);
  
  let fetchData = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${props.address}&key=${
      getEnv().APP_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY
    }`
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === null) return;
    
    // do stuff with `data`
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location)
  }, [data]);
  
  // rest of your component
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: You can't.

So maybe there is a workaround?

Yes

Here it is:

```
(async function(){
let response = await fetch(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${prop.address}&key=${
      getEnv().APP_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY
    }`
  )
response = await response.json()
//and then you can use response in the rest of your code I mean inside of the async function. If you are using node.js, and import node-fetch, then you can just do it without the async function. 
})()
```